# Whenever I bake a normal map via Selected to Active, it bakes the normals of both the high poly and low poly mesh

Tags: normals, texture-baking, baking, normal-map

As the title explains, I'm trying to sculpt some details into a rock and bake them into a normal map. However, whenever I hit bake and check the image, I can see the low poly mesh has been baked into the map along with the high poly mesh. I tried opening a new project and attempted to bake a small dent in a high poly sphere into a low poly one to see if it was just that project, but the same issue occurred. 
Am I missing something that's an easy overlook? I have Active to Selected checked and have selected the high poly first and then the low poly second. If I need to share some screenshots/blend files, just let me know!

Comment: What do you mean by "bakes the normals of the low poly mesh"? Tangent space normal maps are by definition the "difference" between the high and low poly, since the reference space (tangent space) is defined by the low poly geometry. Storing them this way allows the map to remain valid when the low poly deforms.

Comment: Providing some images detailing the issue here: https://imgur.com/a/lxvINe0

I'm new to all this so sorry if I'm not nailing terminology, but I'm not used to seeing normal maps having what looks like the details/faces of the low poly mesh baked in alongside the high poly mesh details, and those faces also appear when using the normal map :(

Comment: ...Wow okay. Welp, just figured it out. I had flat shading on the low poly mesh, has to be smooth to get it to bake out right. I feel dumb now, oops! Thanks for the help though!